# code first mapping part of the table field

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I used the code first, already exists database table t_News, contain fields
Id, NewsTitle, Content, AutoKeywords, Author. But I do not want to entity contains fields Author
So define this entity class:

```
[Table ("t_News")]
public class News
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string NewsTitle {get; set;}
    public string Content {get; set;}
    public string AutoKeywords {get; set;}
}
```

Runtime error:
Unhandled exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'PartCo
ntext 'context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code F
irst Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2
38269).

Comment: do you have a table named __MigrationHistory in your database ?

Comment: No, tnat means that the db has been created by EF. That's also mean that if you want to have two different context for the same db (one with all the column, another with some of them for example) you will have to wait for EF6.  About droping the table... it is possible but you will loose the migration functionnalities of EF.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the migration first. Something like this:

```
Add-Migration "YouMigrationName" -ConnectionString "Data Source=.; Integrated Security=True; Pooling=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient
```

Than you have to update your Database. Here is also some kind of example:

```
Update-Database -ConnectionString "Data Source=.; Integrated Security=True; Pooling=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient
```

Comment: I would also like to retain the "Author" field in the data table

Comment: @user2164641, in this case an EF5 migration is not the way, the column will be droped.

Answer (score 0):

As the __MigrationHistory table exists you are not really in the case of "code first on an existing database", as the database was created, in a way, by EF.

So you can drop the __MigrationHistory. This will bring you in the case "code first on an existing database". BUT YOU HAVE TO CONSIDER what you loose with the droping. That is at least the migration functionalities of EF. So you have to ask you: why this DB was created by EF ? Does __MigrationHistory only impact me ?